# Parametrized queries in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arrays

I am facing a problem with retrieving a column from database

This is my code

```
public String ShowtimeQur(int MovieID)
{
    rs3 = null;
    String  RoomID=null;
    String ShowTime = null;

    try 
    {
        String qu ="Select Room_ID from Movie_Shows_in where Movie_ID="+MovieID;
        //getRoomQur.setInt(1, MovieID);
         rs3=getRoomQur.executeQuery(qu);
        RoomID=rs3.getString("Room_ID");
        getShowtimequr.setString(1, RoomID);
        rs4=getShowtimequr.executeQuery();
        ShowTime=rs4.getString("Show_Times");
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ShowTime;
}
```

I keep get this type of error

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation at current cursor position.

Comment: Please explain your SQL logic and maybe add some sample data.

Comment: Unrelated : variable names go camelCase in Java. So please read about Java naming conventions and adhere to them.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("Select Room_ID from Movie_Shows_in where Movie_ID=?");
statement.setInt(1, MovieID);
ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery()
...
rest of your code
```

Never, never, never use string concatenation to build queries, as you put yourself at risk of [SQL Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer before, you shoud declare a "ResulSet result" variable, and after the execute of the query, you should call "result.next()" method to point the cursor on the first row (initially is pointed to row 0 which does not exist) and then call a retrive data mehod like "result.getString(columnNumber)" by example.